# Jersey Migration from 1.19 to 2.25 Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am migrating from Jerser 1.19 to Jersey 2.25

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to find the suitable jars in Jersey 2.25

I have managed to get these dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

I have not find the equivalent of **`jersey-apache-client`** equilvalent.

Can some one help me if any additional jars are required.

Comment: JAX-RS 2.0 came with an embedded client API. Hence custom client implementations of 1.1 were discontinued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for jersey apache connector. Try following maven dependency -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
```